# Can not adjust radius in leaflet draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am using the new version of  [Leaflet Draw](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/examples/full.html). There is a problem that the radius of a circle can't be edited. The polygon and line can be edited and adjusted. I can move the circle around with edit tool but can not change its radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in `edit/handler/Edit.Circle.js` of the Draw plugin. I've fixed it for now by overriding `L.Edit.Circle`. I just included this in my script:

```
L.Edit.Circle = L.Edit.CircleMarker.extend({
  _createResizeMarker: function () {
    var center = this._shape.getLatLng(),
      resizemarkerPoint = this._getResizeMarkerPoint(center)

    this._resizeMarkers = []
    this._resizeMarkers.push(this._createMarker(resizemarkerPoint, this.options.resizeIcon))
  },

  _getResizeMarkerPoint: function (latlng) {
    var delta = this._shape._radius * Math.cos(Math.PI / 4),
      point = this._map.project(latlng)
    return this._map.unproject([point.x + delta, point.y - delta])
  },

  _resize: function (latlng) {
    var moveLatLng = this._moveMarker.getLatLng()
    var radius

    if (L.GeometryUtil.isVersion07x()) {
      radius = moveLatLng.distanceTo(latlng)
    }
    else {
      radius = this._map.distance(moveLatLng, latlng)
    }

    // **** This fixes the cicle resizing ****
    this._shape.setRadius(radius)

    this._map.fire(L.Draw.Event.EDITRESIZE, { layer: this._shape })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem in this issue:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/pull/968